# Selenium in Python: closing an alert doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, popup, alert

I want my script to fulfill a number of tasks and then close the browser. The part concerning fulfilling a number of tasks works very well. The problem is the browser gets closed a bit too early, before the last task gets finished.

So I added waiting.

However, after I've added it, the browser closing bit doesn't seem to work anymore.

The message is there's an alert open:

> (UnexpectedAlertPresentException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : })

My understanding is that the browser can't be closed because of an alert and yes, in fact there's an alert in my window at the end of the task - when the browser is expected to close:

[image]

The element seems to have this html code:

*Alert:*

```
<td><span class="dialogTitle" tabindex="0"><img src="/analytics/res/v-cAgV78wWw*M/s_blafp/uicomponents/common/title_tick.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" style="margin-right: 6px;">Confirmation</span></td>
```

*Close button*

```
<td class="dialogCloseIconCell"><span class="dialogCloseIcon" title="Close" style="background-image: url(&quot;/analytics/res/v-cAgV78wWw*M/s_AssecoBS/master/close_ena.png&quot;);"></span></td>
```

*Ok button*

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="masterToolbarTextButton button" name="OK" tabindex="0" style="display: inline-block;">OK</a>
```

So I now want to close the alert window, but this doesn't seem to work. The whole script at this stage is:

```
driver.get('MY WEBSITE')

menu = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Export") # And a few other tasks I skip here

actions = ActionChains(driver) 
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.perform()      # It works fine till now

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

alert = driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss() # I also tried out alert.accept(), which no success

driver.quit()
```

The message is:

> NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the pop up?

Comment: Is that only HTML you have got? Where is the element of close button?

Comment: @KunduK, added.

Comment: I have posted an answer check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('dialogTitle').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

If this dosen't work then post the html script of the button

Comment: It actually works, thanks, but the rest of the code that comes after the line doesn't for some reason (it was driver.get).

Comment: Use that line after implicity wait and remove the switch to alert dismiss line.If my answer helped then click the tick button non the left of my answer to mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

To click on **Close** button Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use the following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='dialogCloseIcon' and @title='Close']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Please note : if you get `timeout exception` then check if the element is present inside any `iframe`.